# MySQL C API custom values

Tags: mysql, c

I have been working with the tutorial on MySQL C API from http://zetcode.com/tutorials/mysqlcapitutorial/ the following example is working fine:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

MYSQL *conn;

conn = mysql_init(NULL);
mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "zetcode", "passwd", "testdb", 0, NULL, 0);

mysql_query(conn, "CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))");

mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Leo Tolstoy')");
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Jack London')");
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Honore de Balzac')");
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Lion Feuchtwanger')");
mysql_query(conn, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('Emile Zola')");

mysql_close(conn);

}
```

How can i change the code to accept custom values instead of the hardcoded ones, is it possible to replace writers and ex. Leo Tolstoy with a char pointer or something?

Answer (score 3):

You have basically two options:

- You can construct the query yourself, using `sprintf`. Then you should use [`mysql_real_escape_string`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html) on all your variables, otherwise your code is vulnerable to SQL injection.
- You can use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/c-api-prepared-statements.html). The documentation for [`mysql_stmt_execute`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-stmt-execute.html) has some examples. (this is the better option)

Comment: Regarding escaping strings, this only applies to user-supplied values.  You should take care to differentiate between safe and unsafe data.

Comment: Well, there are no "safe" data. Either you have variables that come from files, user input, etc. or you have constants in your code. Even with constants, I'd rather let the MySQL client to do the escaping, because it knows better than me what to escape.

Answer (score 0):

You will likely have to compose your strings, e.g. using `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use [`sprintf()` / `snprintf()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sprintf.html), as for example:

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
MYSQL *conn;
conn = mysql_init(NULL);
/* error checking missing */
mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "zetcode", "passwd", "testdb", 0, NULL, 0);
/* error checking missing */
mysql_query(conn, "CREATE TABLE writers(name VARCHAR(25))");
/* error checking missing */
do {
    char cmd[1000];
    char *name = "Leo Tolstoy"; /* get from user or file or something */
    snprintf(cmd, 999, "INSERT INTO writers VALUES('%s')", name);
    /* error checking missing */
    mysql_query(conn, cmd);
    /* error checking missing */
} while (0);
mysql_close(conn);
/* error checking missing */
}
```

Comment: Might i add if your going to do it this way and get the input from ... well ... anywhere, your going to want to `mysql_real_escape_string` all of your variable to make sure that you don't fall victim to a SQL injection attack as stated by @Lukáš Lalinský [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-real-escape-string.html)